# How can I define a one-time event so that new handlers fire (once) even after the event has already occurred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

You know how this:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

will fire whether or not the "document ready" event has already occurred?  I want to define an event like that.

That event is a special case in jQuery.  I'm wondering if a custom event can behave in the same way, using only the standard event mechanisms?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to define handlers in the "normal" way:

```
$(document).on("init.mything", function() { ... });
```

This works now if the above runs before `init.mything` is triggered.  But if it doesn't, then the handler never runs.

What makes this tricky is, I don't want to assume anything except that jQuery has loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't catch an event that was triggered before binding. You may want to try explicitly triggering the event after defining the handler and using a boolean to check if it has already fired before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've got all the jQuery plugin coding right, but I think this basic structure should do it for you:

```
;(function ($) {
     $.fn.initMyThing(fn) {
         if (this.data('mything_init')) {
             fn.apply(this);
         } else {
             this.on("init.mything", function() {
                 $(this).data('mything_init', true);
                 fn.apply(this);
         }
     }
 })(jQuery);
```

It means you have to use the syntax

```
$(selector).initMyThing(function() ...);
```

rather than `.on()` to establish the handler.  The only reason document.ready works the way it does is because jQuery treats it specially.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm thinking that the only answer is to put something like this in the client code.  If this is part of the plugin, then assuming it has run is effectively the same as assuming that the init event has completed (in this case, the init event is synchronous).

Comment: Well, I tried to make it more general, in that it uses `.data()` to keep separate state for each element you bind it to.

Comment: I appreciate that.  I ended up just putting an `isReady` flag on my object itself so that the test is a little more concise, but your version would work with no modification to the lib.